# How to clear a text field using UIAutomation

Tags: javascript, ios, ios-ui-automation

I'm trying to make sure a text field is clear before I type text into it. There's some state saving issues where this text field keeps getting populated. If there's an easy way to just clear it that would be great. Note that there is no clear button in this text field (the little x). The only option I see is to use the keyboard and press the back button over and over until this text field is cleared. That also means I'll need to be able to extract the text from the text field to know when it is empty. Anyways, does anyone know what the name of the key is on the keyboard for the back button? I've tried "back" and "delete" and both did not work.

```
function typeNewUserNameAndGoNext()
{
    target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().scrollViews()[0].scrollViews()[0].textFields()[0].tap();
    target.frontMostApp().keyboard().buttons()["delete"].tap(); //what goes in place of delete?
    target.frontMostApp().keyboard().typeString("AutomatedTestUser");
    target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().scrollViews()[0].scrollViews()[0].buttons()[2].tap();    
}
```

Obviously I would wrap that back button press into a loop until the text field is cleared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind I got it by using the recorder.

```
target.frontMostApp().keyboard().keys()["Delete"].touchAndHold(3.6);
```

where you hold for as long as you need until it erases everything.

Comment: touchAndHold might not be appropriate here (Time depends on the performance). Get the length of the text in textfield and tap the key that many times. (Hope the text wont be too long)

Answer (score 0):

Personally I prefer to manually tell the field to set the value to empty string.

target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().textFields()[0].setValue(""); //This always works best for me

The downside to this is that it does not simulate pushing back on the keyboard rather than directly manipulating the field.

However if you were interested in tapping that button the correct number of times you could use a loop and make the conditional str.length > 0.

If you ever need to determine how UIA might be viewing something it is useful to use Instruments and to slowly click through things, Instruments will show you commands for they keyboard as well.